# Garageband On Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Can anyone please tell me any way to install garageband (Music composing app) on a windows 10 pc. Have tried all the methods that popped up on google search none of the really worked for me!

Comment: It's perfectly clear what OP is asking, and the answer is very clear as well and has already been given. This may look like a dumb question to many of us, but that doesn't make it a bad or unclear question.

Comment: @music2myear It's a bad question because what the OP needs is a license and where to get a license is a shopping question, and those are specifically off topic here.

Comment: @davidSchwartz that may be the solution, but that is not what the question was. Because the question does not assume a need to purchase, even though we can correct that misconception in the answer, it does not constitute a shopping request.

Comment: @music2myear The question doesn't assume anything. But the first thing you would need to install Garage Band on Windows 10 would be a license. How you get one would be a shopping request. It might not have been obvious to the OP that it's a shopping request, but that's because the OP didn't do any research. (An independent additional reason this is a bad question.)

Comment: "Have tried all the methods that popped up on google search none of the really worked for me" doesn't tell people here what you tried and in what way it didn't work.  Without clarification, people will waste time writing answers that duplicate what you've already tried.  Also, if none of the existing solutions work, it may be related to your system.  The question provides no specifics other than Win 10.  That said, you have an answer explaining why it can't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Garage Band is only available for macOS and iOS. (It's an Apple product, after all.) There is no Windows version available, nor is there any way to run it on a Windows system.